# Save objects by looping through their names that are in a character vector

Tags: r

I know how to save different files by simply using the loop variable in the file argument of `save()` but I also want the objects in my environment to be named differently. This doesn't seem to work.

```
myvec <- c("a", "b", "c")

for(i in myvec){
 Data <- i
  name <- paste0("Data_", i)
  assign(name, Data)
  save(paste0("Data_", i), 
       file = paste0("Data_", i))
  # what would work:
  # save(Data_a,
  #      file = paste0("Data_", i))
}
```

Comment: You could create an object vector and a filename vector and parallel map over them (`purrr::pmap()`)?

Comment: Learn to work with lists. You should never misuse assign like this.

Comment: I understand the point about lists, I don't understand in what way I am "misusing" assign. Should assign not be used in loops? Why?

Comment: also, the answer seems to be as simple as "use list=..." and all my misusing seems to work?

Comment: The purpose of `assign` is control over which environment you assign into. It is isn't for polluting your global environment with objects that you create iteratively. Next you'll start using `get` to iterate over these objects. If you simply use a `list` as the R developers intended, you can use `lapply` and other functions to iterate over the objects.

Comment: I see, thanks. `get()` is indeed what I was planning to do. I understand lists but the nice thing about this iterative appraoch is that I can `remove()` and `gc()` in between if data gets big (which it doesn't in this case) while the list fills up RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reproducible example here or description of problem.

I guess `myvec` is a vector of character objects, corresponding to names of objects in the namespace, such as `myvec <- ls()`.

The issue seems to be this step `assign(name, Data)`. Where `Data <- i` means that `Data` is still just the character *name* of the object, and not the object itself.

I think you can change `Data <- i` to `Data <- get(i)` and you will get the right results. The other issue is inconsistency: you are trying to save `Data_x` but you never created `Data_x` to the namespace. Lastly, if you want to name the saved object as a character vector, you must explicitly invoke `name=` as the argument for saving.

For example:

```
## rm(list=ls()) NOT RUN
x <- 20
y <- 10
myvec <- c('x', 'y')

for (i in myvec) {
  Data <- get(i)
  name <- paste0("Data_", i)
  assign(name, Data)
  save(list=name, 
     file = paste0("Data_", i, '.rData'))
}
## rm(list=ls()) 
load('./Data_x.rData')
```

Comment: sorry, myvec was simply c("a", "b", "c"). Updated

Answer (score 1):

This is what list objects are for. You can create a list, then save objects inside it with the name you want, and then easily retrieve them by calling their names or positions as an element of said list.

Create a list like this `Data <- list()`, then save the objects inside the list with the name you want: `Data[[paste0("Data_", i)]] <- i`, and finally retrieve the data from the list like this `Data[["Data_a"]]` or `Data$Data_a`.

Comment: Thanks, this works. It does, depending on the circumstances, create a pretty big object (the list) though that I thought could be avoided by saving iteratively. It was worth a try!